# Lookup on People o Group column in SharePoint

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I have a list say 'Source' from which I am using 'Title'(Single line of text) field as Lookup column in another list say 'destination'. 
Now I want to access secondary column value from 'Source' list, say the column is **'property Manager'(person or group)** to be generated or mapped to a new column in my 'destination' list once I select 'Title' from 'Destination' list.

Is it possible to achieve this using OOTB or should I go for custom coding(If so how).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with the Lookup column and selecting "**Add a column to show each of these additional fields**" but there are some limitations for this approach.

You can do it for only ID, Number, SingleLine of Text & Date Time columns.

As you are looking for "Person or Group" field it is **not possible OOTB**

**My Recommendation:**

1. Create a field for "Person or Group" in Destination list
2. In the New/Edit/Disp forms hide the above column using [JSLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745867.aspx)
3. While selecting Title field on the above forms get the corresponding value of Person or Group of the Title field from Source list using CSOM and fill in the hidden Person or Group field in the New/Edit forms of the Destination list

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I don't have permission to modify New/Edit/Disp form in any way. I think using CSOM, I have to fetch the person name based on Title field from 'source' and then I can add this person into my 'destination' list???

Comment: In either way you have to write Javascript CSOM to get the corresponding "Person or Group" value of the Title from Source list to destination. But in the New and Edit forms the "Person or Group" field will be visible. So I was asking you to hide it with the help of JSLink


Solution 2: 

Write an ItemAdded and ItemUpdated event receivers on the destination list items to fetch the corresponding "Person or Group" value of the Title from Source list to destination. But still you got hide the "Person or Group" field on the New/Edit forms using JSLink

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks Naveen. Your recommendation did help me to make some logic but in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the help of SharePoint Designer List Workflow which I created on my destination list. Once the item is added in my Destination list, it will trigger my workflow where I used **Update List Item action** through this I was able to retrieve the property Manager's name by comparing source list and destination list property names. But most importantly I had to create **SPD lookups** for retrieving and comparing list field values. (Creating lookup is really very powerful functionality in SPD Workflow).
Basically I updated my list's Manager field using workflow after adding the item.